# How can I retry copy of a locked files 5 times with Powershell script?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, scripting

How can I loop my powershel script? It copies the local NTUSER.DAT to the file server, I understand that the local NTUSER.DAT file may be locked by the operating system so my COPY may fail. I need it to try and run the script 5 times until it ultimately may fail.. I'm hoping by the 5th try the NTUSER.DAT file is no longer inuse by the operating system.

```
    start-sleep -s 50

$time = Get-Date -Format "hh:mm"
Add-Content -Path "C:\Temp\time.txt" -Value "Script ran at $time"

$FQDN = "$Env:UserDomain"
$User = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | Sort-Object -Property LastLogon -Descending | Select-Object -Property * -First 1 | Where-Object {$_.LastLogon -match "(\d{14})"} | Foreach-Object { New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name=$_.Name.TrimStart("$FQDN\") }} | Select -ExpandProperty Name


copy-item -path  C:\Users\$User\NTUSER.DAT -destination \\10.10.10.10\Profiles$\$user.V2\ -force
copy-item -path  C:\Users\$User\NTUSER.DAT -destination \\10.10.10.10\Profiles$\$user.V3\ -force
```

Comment: No research? First result of google search for: powershell loop

Comment: In addition to the lack of research problem, this suffers from the "wrong way to do it" and probably the "bad idea anyway" problems.  The right way to access locked files is through the use of the Volume Shadow Service, by the way.

Comment: @austinian I wasn't aware there was a strict google policy. I had already used google to research and did go through some exercises on my end. Unfortunately my expertise of Powershell only took me so far, and thus why I opened this question. I will continue to use google to find the answer to my question.

Thank you.

Comment: @HopelessN00b would you be kind to elaborate furthermore on VSS to access locked files? From what I understand the OS has exclusive rights to NTUSER.DAT until it offloads it and no longer needs it. I don't think the VSS will have access to it as it's opened by the OS in exclusive mode. I may be wrong and open to your further advice.

Thank you.

Comment: @user3591436 I was commenting about the question asked, not commenting on the content of the script. There's a strict research policy, not a strict google policy. The google results work fine for looping in a powershell script, especially the do while loop, which is the question you ask, the content of the script is just extra. As for the content of the script, HopelessN00b is correct about accessing the file using VSS. If you research how to copy files using VSS, say, using this search: copy files using vss, and end up with a question based on that, then that would be an appropriate question.

Comment: Ok, I will figure out how to loop my script on my own with Google search results. 

Thank you.

Comment: @user3591436 `I don't think the VSS will have access to it as it's opened by the OS in exclusive mode. I may be wrong and open to your further advice.`  Yeah, you're not quite right there.  Look into techniques and tools for exploring VSS copies/volumes and you should be able to find what you need to extract a copy of `ntuser.dat`.  That's a whole other question though, and far too long to cram into the character limit in these comments.

Comment: The simple solution is to use `robocopy` because you can just tell it how many times to retry. It will try forever if you want.

Answer (score 3):

not the best but works :)

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$counter = 0
Copy-Item SOURCE DEST

if (!($?))
{
  while (!($?))
  {
    $counter++
    Start-Sleep -Seconds (Get-Random -Minimum 30 -Maximum 90)
    Copy-Item SOURCE DEST

    if ($counter -eq 4)
    {
        "Couldn't Copy File"
        return
    }
    elseif($?){"File Copied at $counter try"}
  }

}
else { "File Copied" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) instead of copy-item within powershell.

```
& robocopy $source $destination /COPYALL /R:5
```

R:5 = Retry 5 times

W:50 = Wait time between retries - default is 30 seconds

(The exit codes are a bit different if you use those)

Edit: As kevmar pointed out in his comment, I missed that sorry!